Assistance in Designing a Use Case Diagram for User Interactions
Can you please help me in the use case diagram for user in my web app:
the user can browse trips
can create trip (login is required)
can view profile(login is required)
share trip (login is required)
manage trip (login is required)
view their trips list (login is required)

Is the direction of the <<include>> relationship correct?

These are not use cases, but functions of an application. Use cases are the main goals a user has when using your application. From what I can see you would probably only need a single use case. Something like Manage Trips

This question is similar to: What's is the difference between include and extend in use case diagram?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is a nice and comprehensive diagram, which is syntactically correct and uses good naming practice (just small typo "Mange"). But although not wrong, most of the use cases do not correspond to real use cases.
Indeed, this design is focused on user interactions and how these interaction should look like (e.g. the "view profile" would allow to "edit"), instead of considering the user goals (e.g. "manage trips") and why the user would want to use the system.
As a result the diagram mixes a functional decomposition at the granularity of the user interface, with some logical flow from login to logout (disguised as extension and inclusion). This is far too detailed, and will not be useful if you want to discuss it with users, who will be submerged by its apparent complexity. This even misleads: Viewing a trip is definitely not a behavior included in login. Login is not even a real use case. Logout does not extend viewing a profile (except if you you interpret the extension as a kind of navigation in the user interface -- but there are better tools for modeling user interface)). Moreover, use-cases are not meant to be ordered. Other diagrams are more suitable for this.
My recommendation is therefore to cut radically into this diagram and keep only 3 to 6 main use cases. Those that correspond to the main goals of the user. Avoid extension and inclusion as much as possible.
Then put the additional details (the logical flow with the details) into separate activity diagrams, with each activity diagram being simple and describing the set of behaviors of one use-case.
